# How to validate API response in RTK Query using Zod schema?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query, zod

I want to validate the API response that I'm getting from a REST API using a Zod schema. For example, I have this user schema and this API

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';


const userSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
});

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;


export const userAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userAPI',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://some-api/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<user, string>({
      query: (id) => `user/${id}`,
    }),
  }),
})
```

I want to validate the API response against the userSchema using Zod. However, I'm unsure whether to use the parse or safeParse function provided by Zod.

Could you please clarify where in my code should I perform the response validation, and whether I should use parse or safeParse for this scenario?

Comment: You have `builder.query<user, string>` which types the response/return value as `user`. Do you need *more* than this? What is `user` here as a type? Should you instead be using the `User` type that was inferred from the schema?

Comment: That just specifies what type of data you are expecting from the API, but it does not validate that the response you are getting is actually of that type. It is mostly enough if you are making the API in-house, but not if you are working with third-party APIs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use `transformResponse` provided by redux toolkit query to validate the response using the userSchema. If the response doesn't match the schema, an error will be triggered.

```js
import { z } from 'zod';
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';

const userSchema = z.object({
  id: z.string(),
  name: z.string(),
  age: z.number(),
});

type User = z.infer<typeof userSchema>;

export const userAPI = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'userAPI',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: 'https://some-api/' }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getPokemonByName: builder.query<User, string>({
      query: (id) => `user/${id}`,
      transformResponse: (response) => {
        userSchema.parse(response);
        return response;
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

[You can also write a wrapper for baseQuery with zod](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/discussions/3404#discussioncomment-5741821)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback and the codesandbox